# Java - Unable to access protected method of superclass extended by nested class

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes, protected

I'm new to java and getting the hang of protected visibility.

I have Class A which has protected method method1 as follows -

```
public abstract class A { 
    public A(...){}

    protected void method1(){
        // do something
    }
```

Now I have another Class B which extends a different Class C. Class B has a nested static class, Class D extending Class A

```
public class B extends C {
    public B(...){
        super(...);
    }

    private static class D extends A {
        D(...){super(...);}
    }

    public void method2() {
        D record = new D();
        record.method1(); // need to access the protected method1 of class A, which is the superclass of nested class D. Getting the error here
    }
}
```

I get this error - method1 has protected access in Class A
Now my question is how can I access method1? I cannot change it to public in class A

Comment: method1 is not static, so you cannot use `D.method1();`, you need to use `record.method1()`. I guess this is what you wanted to do anyways because `record` is not used otherwise.

Comment: `record.method1()`. The method isn't static, so you call it on an instance of A

Comment: My bad that was a typing error, I am indeed accessing it using record.method1(). But still unable to access it.

Comment: One warning: sind java 15 there exists `record` - an immutable class for tuples, like `record Complex(double re, double im) {}; Complex z = new Complex(3.0, 4.0); double r = Math.hypot(z.re(), z.im());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a proxy method in class D as outlined below. Class D can access Class A's protected methods, but an instance of Class D can't call protected methods directly, and must have a proxy method to call the protected method of the super class.

In class D, you need to create a public getter for the method in Class A, so:

```
public class A {
    protected void protectedMethod() {}
}

public class D extends A {
    public void callProtectedMethod() {
        super.protectedMethod();
    }
}

final D record = new D();

record.callProtectedMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since A.method1() is protected, it is only accessible from same class/same package/child of A.

In your code, your are calling A.method1() in B, that is not accessible if B not in same package as A

The solution is using a wrapper  as @Alex Ander or change modifier of A.method1() to public

[image: Java Access Modifiers]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, B is indeed not in the same package as A. using the wrapper worked.

Comment: Yeah, of course it work. But I would recommend you learn the mean of modifiers so that you can design java code more reasonable

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the protected `method1()` called from `method2()`, which belongs to B, which is outside A and D, and B is not in the same package with A or D.

The `method1()` should only used/called inside A or D. That's what `protected` is used for, to ensure it is used only in the owner class, its inheriting classes or from the same package.

That's why when the wrapper method created inside D, the problem solved, since the protected `method1()` is called from inside D.

We still can override the protected `method1()` of A and make it public through D if necessary. (Modified from the wrapper example above)

```
class A {
    protected void protectedMethod() {}
}

class D extends A {
    @Override
    public void protectedMethod() {
        super.protectedMethod();
    }
}

final D record = new D();
record.protectedMethod();
```